# Three different dataframes rows combination

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, iterator

i am trying to create combinations of three different pandas dataframes splitted rows. I got three dataframe and

```
    A  B
X1  1  1
X2  2  2
X3  3  3
X4  4  4


    C   D
Y1  5   8
Y2  6   9
Y3  7  10


     E
Z1  11
Z2  12
```

i am trying to handle df1,2,3,4....24 dataframe producted. 3 dataframe splitted into rows and product i mean combinations of these rows like.

```
df1   df2   df3   df4   df5   df6   df7   df8
X1|   X1|   X2|   X2|   X3|   X3|   X4|   X4
Y1|   Y1|   Y1|   Y1|   Y1|   Y1|   Y1|   Y1
Z1|   Z2|   Z1|   Z2|   Z1|   Z2|   Z1|   Z2

df9 df10 df11 df12 df13 df14 df15 df16
X1|  X1|  X2|  X2|  X3|  X3|  X4|  X4
Y2|  Y2|  Y2|  Y2|  Y2|  Y2|  Y2|  Y2
Z1|  Z2|  Z1|  Z2|  Z1|  Z2|  Z1|  Z2

df17  df18  df19  df20  df21  df22  df23 df24
X1|   X1|   X2|   X2|   X3|   X3|   X4|   X4
Y3|   Y3|   Y3|   Y3|   Y3|   Y3|   Y3|   Y3
Z1|   Z2|   Z1|   Z2|   Z1|   Z2|   Z1|   Z2
```

I'm trying to get as quickly as possible. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use itertools product to get the combinations of rows you are looking for, and for each set of combinations filter to the rows in that set.  Putting each resulting dataframe into a list, you can call the list with the iteration number you want to see the results.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': {'X1': 1, 'X2': 2, 'X3': 3, 'X4': 4},
 'B': {'X1': 1, 'X2': 2, 'X3': 3, 'X4': 4}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C': {'Y1': 5, 'Y2': 6, 'Y3': 7}, 'D': {'Y1': 8, 'Y2': 9, 'Y3': 10}})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'E': {'Z1': 11, 'Z2': 12}})

df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])

output = []


for p in product(*[df1.index,df2.index,df3.index]):
    output.append(df[df.index.isin(p)])

output[5]

      A   B   C   D       E
X1  1.0 1.0 NaN  NaN    NaN
Y3  NaN NaN 7.0 10.0    NaN
Z2  NaN NaN NaN  NaN   12.0

output[20]

      A   B   C   D    E
X4  4.0 4.0 NaN NaN  NaN
Y2  NaN NaN 6.0 9.0  NaN
Z1  NaN NaN NaN NaN 11.0
```